# Compare a textbox entry to a column that contains text( alphanumeric with '-') , if a duplicate is found then alert user

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2010

I have a column that contains text made up of alphanumeric characters with a special character '-' like Kat-1, Amp-2, Xua-09, etc. I tried the below code, but it does not seem to recognize text like Kat-1 as a duplicate. Can anyone  please check what is wrong with this code.

```
Private Sub txt_BPName_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim myrange As Range
Dim match As Boolean
Dim val
Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
match = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrange, val) > 0
If match Then
MsgBox ("Duplicate")
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't define "val"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the instr() function.  You can iterate through your column and compare each cell in the column to your text box value with a for loop. That is probably the easiest solution. If you post an excerpt of your speadsheet it would be easier to edit your function to work.

Comment: `Private Sub txt_BPName_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
For Each c In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
        If c.Value = txt_BPName Then MsgBox "Cell " & c.Address & " is a duplicate."
Next c
 Cancel = True
 End Sub`             This code here is finding duplicates, but the only issue is it is finding my immediate entry on a text box as a duplicate. Any idea on how to avoid this.  @user3598756 @Tyler Denton

Comment: I dont really understand the problem you are having but this will work. Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim Match As String
Dim row As Integer
Dim here As Integer
here = 0

With ActiveSheet
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Match = Me.TextBox1.Text

For I = 1 To x
    here = InStr(.Cells(I, 1), Match)
    If here <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Match at row " + Str(I))
    End If
    here = 0
Next I

End With
End Sub